# Is there any Java library to parse a simple grammar?

Tags: java, parsing

I want to use Java to parse a very simple grammar, for example:

```
/*comments*/
"aaa" = "bbb"
```

That's all. I want all tokens (comment, string, equals).

Is there any Java library that can handle this?

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you looking for something like ANTLR? http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: @zengr I believe so. Please follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278480/antlr-tutorials and this http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2008.htm

Comment: Maybe OP only wants the tokens and not an actual parser for the implied simple grammar?

Comment: ANTLR might be a little too heavy for such a simple thing. but if you all recommend ANTLR, I'll try it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You gonna have to write the base grammar that recognize everyone of these tokens and then generate the parser (lexical and syntaxic) with a tool like [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) or [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) (They both produce Java classes). Then you'll have a parser that can parse your language.

I hope it is what you meant by `parse a [...] grammar`.

Answer (score 1):

for really basic needs you can use either  java.util.StringTokenizer or java.io.StreamTokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can code a recursive descent parser pretty easily for a simple language.  See [Is there an alternative for flex/bison that is usable on 8-bit embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)